# PHP loop through array and split into seperate arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Hi I have this PHP array of Amazon Sub Categories what I am trying to do is loop through the array and split into 3 seperate ones,

Heres the Array, and needs to be split into 3 arrays $request, and all the children under it $subCats and final variable $Ancestors.  The $subCats will contain all the [Children][BrowseNode].  Its driving me mad I cant seem to loop through correctly.

Any thoughts people.  Cheers in advanced.

J.

```
Array
(
    [Request] => Array
        (
            [IsValid] => True
            [BrowseNodeLookupRequest] => Array
                (
                    [BrowseNodeId] => 66471031
                    [ResponseGroup] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => BrowseNodeInfo
                        )

                )

        )

    [BrowseNode] => Array
        (
            [BrowseNodeId] => 66471031
            [Name] => Beauty
            [Children] => Array
                (
                    [BrowseNode] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [BrowseNodeId] => 118423031
                                    [Name] => Cosmetics
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [BrowseNodeId] => 74006031
                                    [Name] => Cosmetics_hidden
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [BrowseNodeId] => 118457031
                                    [Name] => Fragrances
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [BrowseNodeId] => 66466031
                                    [Name] => Fragrances_hidden
                                )


                        )

                )

            [Ancestors] => Array
                (
                    [BrowseNode] => Array
                        (
                            [BrowseNodeId] => 66280031
                            [Name] => Categories
                            [IsCategoryRoot] => 1
                            [Ancestors] => Array
                                (
                                    [BrowseNode] => Array
                                        (
                                            [BrowseNodeId] => 65801031
                                            [Name] => Health & Beauty
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What code arey you using? Where are you stuck?

Comment: PHP mate, I can loop through the array but I dont know how to get to the [Children][BrowseNodes] level so I can drag out the sub cat names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$request = your_main_array['request'];
$subCats = your_main_array['BrowseNode']['Children']['BrowseNode'];
$Ancestors = your_main_array['BrowseNode']['Ancestors']
```

['Children']['BrowseNode'] and ['Ancestors'] are in a [BrowseNode] Array under you main array.

Comment: Cheers araf!  Nice one so simple!  Been looking at the code to long!